# jvm crash after system upgrade

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, tomcat5.5

We have a tomcat application that started crashing every 10-15 minutes after we upgraded the OS ("aptitude dist-upgrade" of the system, which is a 32-bit Debian Lenny).  java didn't get upgraded.
A Full thread dump is generated in catalina.out when jvm crashes. But there is no error/exception showing in any of the threads.  Does anyone know what might have caused the problem?  Thanks.

Here is the beginning of thread dump:

```
Mar 6, 2010 7:00:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_17-b04 mixed mode):

"Thread-27" prio=1 tid=0x082f5aa8 nid=0xe95 waiting on condition [0xa1bfc000..0xa1bfce30]
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:495)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:645)

"SIGHUP handler" daemon prio=1 tid=0xa4ce85d0 nid=0xe93 in Object.wait() [0xa1cfe000..0xa1cfef30]
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on  (a org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1095)
        - locked  (a org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1148)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:132)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:173)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:218)
        - locked  (a java.lang.Class)
        at java.lang.Terminator$1.handle(Terminator.java:35)
        at sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:195)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

"http-8080-Monitor" prio=1 tid=0xa3ff1780 nid=0xbb4 in Object.wait() [0xa1eea000..0xa1eeafb0]
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:564)
        - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

"http-8080-Processor25" daemon prio=1 tid=0xa3ff0aa8 nid=0xbb3 sleeping[0xa1f6b000..0xa1f6c030]
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:62)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
.....
```

Following are what got updated in the upgraded

```
[UPGRADE] base-files 5lenny4 -> 5lenny5
[UPGRADE] bind9-host 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] dnsutils 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] dpkg 1.14.25 -> 1.14.28
[UPGRADE] dselect 1.14.25 -> 1.14.28
[UPGRADE] filter-syslog 1.22-1 -> 1.23-1
[UPGRADE] gzip 1.3.12-6 -> 1.3.12-6+lenny1
[UPGRADE] krb5-clients 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny1 -> 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny2
[UPGRADE] krb5-rsh-server 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny1 -> 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny2
[UPGRADE] krb5-user 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny1 -> 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny2
[UPGRADE] libbind9-40 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] libc6 2.7-18 -> 2.7-18lenny2
[UPGRADE] libc6-dev 2.7-18 -> 2.7-18lenny2
[UPGRADE] libc6-i686 2.7-18 -> 2.7-18lenny2
[UPGRADE] libdns45 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] libexpat1 2.0.1-4+lenny1 -> 2.0.1-4+lenny3
[UPGRADE] libisc45 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] libisccc40 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] libisccfg40 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] libkadm55 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny1 -> 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny2
[UPGRADE] libkrb53 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny1 -> 1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5lenny2
[UPGRADE] libltdl3 1.5.26-4 -> 1.5.26-4+lenny1
[UPGRADE] liblwres40 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1 -> 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
[UPGRADE] libmysqlclient15off 5.0.51a-24+lenny2 -> 5.0.51a-24+lenny3
[UPGRADE] libpq5 8.3.8-0lenny1 -> 8.3.9-0lenny1
[UPGRADE] libssl0.9.8 0.9.8g-15+lenny5 -> 0.9.8g-15+lenny6
[UPGRADE] libxerces2-java 2.9.1-2 -> 2.9.1-2+lenny1
[UPGRADE] linux-image-2.6.26-2-686 2.6.26-19lenny2 -> 2.6.26-21lenny3
[UPGRADE] linux-libc-dev 2.6.26-19lenny2 -> 2.6.26-21lenny3
[UPGRADE] locales 2.7-18 -> 2.7-18lenny2
[UPGRADE] login 1:4.1.1-6 -> 1:4.1.1-6+lenny1
[UPGRADE] munin-node 1.2.6-10~lenny1 -> 1.2.6-10~lenny2
[UPGRADE] mysql-common 5.0.51a-24+lenny2 -> 5.0.51a-24+lenny3
[UPGRADE] openssl 0.9.8g-15+lenny5 -> 0.9.8g-15+lenny6
[UPGRADE] passwd 1:4.1.1-6 -> 1:4.1.1-6+lenny1
[UPGRADE] python2.5 2.5.2-15 -> 2.5.2-15+lenny1
[UPGRADE] python2.5-minimal 2.5.2-15 -> 2.5.2-15+lenny1
[UPGRADE] sudo 1.6.9p17-2 -> 1.6.9p17-2+lenny1
[UPGRADE] tzdata 2009l-0lenny1 -> 2010a-0lenny1
[UPGRADE] usbutils 0.73-10 -> 0.73-10lenny1
[UPGRADE] wallet-client 0.9-1 -> 0.10-1~sbp50+1
```

Comment: Please post the crash report.

Comment: There is no crash report generated.  There is a full java thread dump in catalina.out, but showing no error.  Before the thread dump, these lines are displayed in the log:
Mar 7, 2010 12:00:01 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

It leads me to think that maybe tomcat is existing for some reason.  We reverted the OS changes made, the application is functioning normal again.  We are still trying to figure out what caused the problem so that we can performed the upgrade at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This could be tricky.  Java 5.0 is past its EOL date and no new public updates are being produced.  The last update was 5.0 update 21.  You can download it from the [Java product archive](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/) page, but there are no guarantees this will fix the problem.  (I cannot find the release notes for Java 5.0 on the Sun website, but even they might not answer the question.)

So, your options are:

- download the last 5.0 update and see if that fixes the problem, or
- upgrade to Java 6.0.